# Class with model could not be found in Lumen

Tags: laravel, lumen

In my web browser I am getting this error:

> FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 18:
>
> Class 'App\Report'
> not found

It seems that UserControler.php page cannot find report.php page.

Here is my folder structure:

```
lumen
-api
--report.php // file where model Report is
---Http
----Controller
------UserController.php // file where i get error
-bootstrap
- ...
```

Header of UserController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;  
use App\Report; // it seems here is problem
use App\User; // with user model is same problem
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
  
class UserController extends Controller {
...
```

Header of report.php

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Report extends Model {
...
```

I am using Apache, Ubuntu, PHP 5.5 with Lumen framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all model file name should be same as your class name here

```
lumen
-api
--report.php // This should be Report.php
---Http
----Controller
------UserController.php // file where i get error
-bootstrap
- ...
```

Also your **`Report.php`** Model will be under **`app directory same directory where your User Model resides`**

Comment: Reason this worked on XAMPP in Windows, but not on Linux server is because Windows isn't case sensitive. So Windows see report.php and Report.php as same file. Thanx.

Comment: @IvanVulović **`windows file names`** aren't case sensitive where else **`*nix`** are all case sensitive you can create two files or directories with same name but altering case in linux & mac